# How can I add items to a list from a thread and keep the adding order?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to add some items in a list and keep the adding order. The problem is that 
 the adding part is done in a thread because I need to get some details from DB, put them in a
 item and add it to list.

```
public void addNewItem(Step item){

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            item.setDetails(db.getStepDetails(step.getId()));
            add(item);
        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

The `add` method looks like:

```
private void add(Step step){
    mitems.add(step);
}
```

If I do something like

```
 addNewItem(stepA);
 addNewItem(stepB);
```

If the first call take too much time, the second item is added first in my list.

Do you know how can I wait for an action to finish before continue adding any other item in my list?

Thank you.

Comment: I may be wrong but I believe using `synchronize` would fix this

Comment: Do you really want to use a separate Thread? In your case, you precisely need to execute instructions in order.

Comment: A workaround would be a synchronized id that is incremented upon each add and stored in the added item. Then, you could see in the resulting container in what order the items were added.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a synchronized block or use a ReentrantLock.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        synchronized(someSafeVar) {
            item.setDetails(db.getStepDetails(step.getId()));
            add(item);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, if it's only the "add" method that takes time, this method only could be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep your item order if you added the items to your list **before** you set the details.
then you could wait with all following actions until a initialized flag of your items is set:

```
mitems.add(stepA);
mitems.add(stepB)

[...]

ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("GetStepDetailsGroup");

for(Step step : mitems)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(group, new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            item.setDetails(db.getStepDetails(step.getId()));
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}

while(group.activeCount() > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch(InteruptedExpection e) {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single worker thread, and feed it from a queue, and thus you would have a single thread adding to mitems.

You would need to creat two lists in that case, and syncrhonize them.

EG.,

```
List<Step> processingList = new ArrayList<Step>();
List<Step> mitems = new ArrayList<Step>();
public void addNewItem(Step item)
{
  syncrhonized(processingList)
  {
    processingList.add(item);
  }
}
```

The worker thread takes items from the front of processingList, works on them, and adds them to mitems when they are ready.

Comment: i suggest using Queue<Step> for processingList since adding items to the end and retrieving them from the beginning is typical for work with queues

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Dictionary instead:

```
Dictionary mitems = new Hashtable();
```

and

```
mitems.put("1", item);
```

The Key would be the Order then.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it looks like adding the Steps to a List is totally independent of retrieving information from the DB and filling in the Steps.

Therefore, you could just put all your Steps in a List using only one Thread. Then, you would fetch the DB information using Runnables, one for each Step and execute these Runnables in a Executor with as many threads as you like (while still getting a speedup from multithreading).

Answer (score 0):

[Thread#join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

Waits for this thread to die.

Hope this helps,
Yaron